# Does apt-get update keep Ubuntu version unchanged?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

If I have an old version, say 12.04 LTS, installed on my little rooted tablet, and never want to upgrade the version (14.04 is big and XCB window response is sluggish), can I run apt-get update on the command line? Updating the master lists is OK but only if it stays in the context of 12.04. I specifically mean command line, not GUI-based update.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` will (hopefully) update to Ubuntu 12.04.5 .

Answer (score 5):

Yes, running `sudo apt-get update` will not change or update *anything*.

The only thing `apt-get update` does is refresh the local "cache" with the list of available software / packages. It won't update any packages, and it won't upgrade or change your Ubuntu version.

Note that `apt-get upgrade` is different - that *does* actually update things.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `sudo apt-get update` to update the software sources list. It's just a refresh of software names and available versions. No software changes with this commnad.

Do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` to *update* all your software, to the newest version available.

Do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to *upgrade* (entire) Ubuntu from one sub-version to the next sub-version of the same development cycle. E.g. upgrade 12.04.1 to 12.04.2.

Do a `sudo do-release upgrade` to *upgrade* (entire) Ubuntu from one version to another. e.g. 12.04 to 12.10 , 13.10 to 14.04 , etc.

Comment: If you want to upgrade from one release to another from command prompt, you probably should use do-release-upgrade, instead of apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not pull new kernels, since it means new packages. Think you need to read **man apt-get** about the distinction between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`. (`sudo apt upgrade` pulls new kernels, but I don't think that command is available in 12.04.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using apt-get update/upgrade will maintain whatever release you have installed. However, 12.04 is EOL in less than a year.